# Which node is running Cloudera Manager out of N hadoop nodes?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have a large hadoop cluster (24 nodes). I have CLI access to these nodes. First few is not running Cloudera Manager (cloudera-scm-server).

How can I find out which node is running Cloudera Manager?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera Manager will have two services. one is Server another is agents.

As you said you have CLI access to all the node. So run below command on all the nodes to find which is server and open (server will be running on only 1 machine)

`sudo service cloudera-scm-server status`

Another simple method to find CDH Server address

ssh to any node and move to /etc/cloudera-scm-agent. There you will find config.ini file, in that you will find `server_host` address

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to ssh to all 30 nodes :-)  Thank you , though.